# Using unbalanced brace in Roxygen/Rd code example

Tags: r, roxygen2, rd

The following MWE fails to compile (via `devtools::document()`):

```
#' MWE
#'
#' @examples
#' format('{}') # Works
#' format('{')  # Nope
#' format('\{') # Nope
#' format('\\{')# Nope
format = function (str) {}
```

Regardless of which of the “Nope” lines I include, it always fails with the error

> Failure in roxygen block beginning mwe.r:1
>   Mismatched braces …

According to my reading of the [Rd documentation](https://developer.r-project.org/parseRd.pdf), this should work by escaping the brace. However, as shown above, this does *not* work. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Roxygen?

One hint that this might be a Roxygen bug is the full error message when I use the single-escaped version (`format('\{')`):

> Mismatched braces: `"@example format('{}') # Works
>   format('\\{')  # Nope"`

Note that the single backslash in the input has been doubled in the output.

Comment: @Josh Your (now deleted) answer makes this compile but — as you may have noticed, considering the deletion — it results in a broken Rd file that will show errors when attempting to display the help in R. So can we conclude that this is a roxygen bug?

Comment: It sure looks like a bug. I deleted because I realized (duh) that the extra right brace was just being used to close the `\examples{}` section

Comment: Well, bug reported at https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/393

Comment: maybe you can close the question now ?

Comment: @KarlForner Actually if you look at the bug report you’ll see that even with the bug fixed (at least ostensibly), the problem persists. I’m unsure whether this is a bug or whether I’m doing something wrong. At any rate, the original question has evolved by remains essentially unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when this was fixed but with `roxygen2` `version 6.0.1` this issue seems resolved.

`devtools::document()` on the MWE produces a valid Rd:

```
\examples{
format('{}') 
format('{')  
format('\\{') 
format('\\\\{')
}
```